# Find in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional json array:

```
Array(
[LogicTokenList] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [position] => 0
                [lemma] => accendi
                [generalLemma] => accendere
                [extendedPOSTag] => VER:impr+pres+2+s
                [simplifiedPOSTag] => VER
                [rearrangedTag] => VER
                [retrievedRearrangedLemma] => accendere
                [synonymProxyTag] => v.
                [schankDependency] => ATRANS
                [logicAnalysis] => 
                [isWH] => 
                [WHVariant] => 
                [hyperonym] => 
                [isFirstSubject] => 
                [isFirstObject] => 
                [substantivization] => accensione
                [synonyms] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => appiccare il fuoco
                        [1] => attizzare
                        [2] => bruciare
                        [3] => incendiare
                        [4] => infiammare
                    )
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [position] => 1
                [lemma] => la
                [generalLemma] => la
                [extendedPOSTag] => ART-F:s
                [simplifiedPOSTag] => ART
                [rearrangedTag] => ART
                [retrievedRearrangedLemma] => la
                [synonymProxyTag] => ART
                [schankDependency] => 0
                [logicAnalysis] => 
                [isWH] => 
                [WHVariant] => 
                [hyperonym] => 
                [isFirstSubject] => 
                [isFirstObject] => 
                [substantivization] => 
                [synonyms] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => la
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [position] => 2
                [lemma] => luce
                [generalLemma] => Luce
                [extendedPOSTag] => NPR
                [simplifiedPOSTag] => NPR
                [rearrangedTag] => NOU
                [retrievedRearrangedLemma] => luce
                [synonymProxyTag] => sost.
                [schankDependency] => 0
                [logicAnalysis] => COMP_OGG
                [isWH] => 
                [WHVariant] => 
                [hyperonym] => ARTEFATTO
                [isFirstSubject] => 
                [isFirstObject] => 1
                [substantivization] => 
                [synonyms] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => baleno
                        [1] => fulgore
                        [2] => lampo
                        [3] => raggio
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [position] => 3
                [lemma] => della
                [generalLemma] => della
                [extendedPOSTag] => ARTPRE-F:s
                [simplifiedPOSTag] => ARTPRE
                [rearrangedTag] => ARTPRE
                [retrievedRearrangedLemma] => della
                [synonymProxyTag] => ARTPRE
                [schankDependency] => 0
                [logicAnalysis] => 
                [isWH] => 
                [WHVariant] => 
                [hyperonym] => 
                [isFirstSubject] => 
                [isFirstObject] => 
                [substantivization] => 
                [synonyms] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => della
                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [position] => 4
                [lemma] => cucina
                [generalLemma] => cucina
                [extendedPOSTag] => NOUN-F:s
                [simplifiedPOSTag] => NOU
                [rearrangedTag] => NOU
                [retrievedRearrangedLemma] => cucina
                [synonymProxyTag] => sost.
                [schankDependency] => 0
                [logicAnalysis] => COMP_SLUOGO
                [isWH] => 
                [WHVariant] => 
                [hyperonym] => EDIFICIO
                [isFirstSubject] => 
                [isFirstObject] => 
                [substantivization] => 
                [synonyms] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => arte culinaria
                        [1] => gastronomia
                    )

            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [position] => 5
                [lemma] => alle
                [generalLemma] => alla
                [extendedPOSTag] => ARTPRE-F:p
                [simplifiedPOSTag] => ARTPRE
                [rearrangedTag] => ARTPRE
                [retrievedRearrangedLemma] => alla
                [synonymProxyTag] => ARTPRE
                [schankDependency] => 0
                [logicAnalysis] => 
                [isWH] => 
                [WHVariant] => 
                [hyperonym] => 
                [isFirstSubject] => 
                [isFirstObject] => 
                [substantivization] => 
                [synonyms] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => alla
                    )

            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [position] => 6
                [lemma] => 20
                [generalLemma] => 20
                [extendedPOSTag] => NPR
                [simplifiedPOSTag] => NPR
                [rearrangedTag] => NPR
                [retrievedRearrangedLemma] => 20
                [synonymProxyTag] => Numero
                [schankDependency] => 0
                [logicAnalysis] => COMP_TEMPO
                [isWH] => 
                [WHVariant] => 
                [hyperonym] => 
                [isFirstSubject] => 
                [isFirstObject] => 
                [substantivization] => 
                [synonyms] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 20
                    )

            )

    )

[ChosenWHCategory] => ARTEFATTO
[GrammarAnalysisExecutionTime] => 2531
[LogicAnalysisExecutionTime] => 459
)
```

I have decoded with `$json = json_decode($mydata, true);`
But now I need to search in this array, for example if I find the value "VER" in [simplifiedPOSTag], I need to print the [retrievedRearrangedLemma].
An important thing, the position of this array may be change.

Answer (score 0):

you could pass the array to a recursive function

```
function search_array($arr = array()) {
    if (!is_array($arr))
       return;

    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        search_arr($v);

        if ($k == "simplifiedPOSTag" 
               && strpos("VER", $v) !== false
               && !empty($arr["retrievedRearrangedLemma"])) {
            echo $arr["retrievedRearrangedLemma"];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not work, nothing result :( I need to search the [simplifiedPOSTag] => VER in my array and print the value of [retrievedRearrangedLemma]

another example, find the [logicAnalysis] => COMP_SLUOGO (look at position 4) and print the value of [retrievedRearrangedLemma] (in my array is cucina)

Comment: this may be dumb, but are you sure that your JSON is decoding properly into an array?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, try this:

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($json[LogicTokenList]); $i++) {
    if($json[LogicTokenList][$i][simplifiedPOSTag]=='VER') echo $json[LogicTokenList][$i][retrievedRearrangedLemma];
}
```

Comment: Not work, nothing result  :(
I need to search the [simplifiedPOSTag] => VER in my array and print the value of [retrievedRearrangedLemma]

Comment: another example, find the [logicAnalysis] => COMP_SLUOGO  (look at position 4) and print the value of [retrievedRearrangedLemma]    (in my array is cucina)

Comment: Try adding "[LogicTokenList]" after every "$array"

Comment: in this way?

`for($i=0; $i<sizeof($json[LogicTokenList]); $i++) {
    if($json[LogicTokenList][$i][simplifiedPOSTag]=='VER') echo $json[LogicTokenList][$i[retrievedRearrangedLemma]];
}`

Comment: excuse me, the name of array is json in my script

Comment: Ok, we're almost there :)

Comment: Work, perfect!!!!
For the second i use:
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($json[LogicTokenList]); $i++) {
    if($json[LogicTokenList][$i][logicAnalysis]=='COMP_OGG') 
 echo $json[LogicTokenList][$i][retrievedRearrangedLemma];
}